# Distributed ExecutorServices using Spring

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, distributed-computing, spring-cloud

is there a Spring Project (if possible Spring Boot) that allows me do distribute Tasks (e.g., Runnables) among a set of distributed Executor Services.

So usually, what I'm looking for is the following:

I have Master or Orchestration Node that generates a small data processing pipeline (e.g, A->B->C). To launch such a pipeline, the Orchestration Node launches an additional application (the Distributed Executor Service) in a cluster and starts the three tasks on it. As soon as an additional data processing should be started, the tasks are either launched on the already running Distributed Executor Service or a new Distributed Executor Service is started. The approach should be generic so that it doesn't matter if all tasks run on the same Executor Service or on different (tasks are connected via a message broker).

So my concrete questions are:
If there does not exist such a framework yet, which Spring Frameworks (or other Frameworks) might support me in developing such a solution? I was thinking about Spring Cloud (e.g., Data Flow, Stream and Tasks) but they have the disadvantage that usually each task of a pipeline would be a single JVM. However, since there might exist many of those tasks at the same time, I would like to mitigate this.

Thank you for your answers.

Best regards,
André